# Quasi-triangular Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

[image]
Hi, I am reading George E Shilov's Linear Algebra. The attached image is page 23. The author here talks about quasi-triangular matrix. I am not able to understand what this matrix is all about and how to find the determinant of this matrix.

Can someone throw more light on this.

Comment: HINT: to compute the determinant, use Laplace Theorem. This should enable you to prove that $$\det\begin{pmatrix}A & B\\ C& D\end{pmatrix}=\det(A)\det(D)-\det(B)\det(C),$$ if $A,B,C,D$ are square matrices. Now $B=0$ in you case.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion#General_statement